# Emoji from Angularjs $http to PHP json_decode and store in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, emoji

So i am trying to store emojis in my database and return them in my app. I have build a small messanger with ionic v1 and everything works fine. I only want to store the emojis properly and show them in app. My whole database, tables and columns are set to utf8mb4 so I know this is good. When i send it with `$http` to my `php` it also looks okey : `{"from_account_id":"xxxx","for_account_id":"xxxx","message":""}:` But when I print it in `php` it looks like this : `{"from_account_id":"106191","for_account_id":"989014","message":"đ˝"}` and in my mysql everywhere I have put an emoji it shows `?`. What more can I do ? I also have set the header in my php to `UTF_8`. I know there were much question about that but i have followed most of them and It still didn't resolve my problem.

My php where i store the message :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
include_once 'config.php';

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `messages` (`message_id`, `from_account_id`, `for_account_id`, `date_read`, `message`)
      VALUES (NULL, :from_account_id, :for_account_id, NULL, :message)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':from_account_id', $data['from_account_id']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':for_account_id', $data['for_account_id']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':message', $data['message']);
    $stmt->execute();
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
          throw $e;
  }
  echo 'Success';

?>
```

My `AngularJS` function where I send the message :

```
  $scope.sendMessage = function(for_account_id, message){
    if(for_account_id != null && message != null){
    $http({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'myurl',
      data: {
      from_account_id: $rootScope.unique_id,
      for_account_id: for_account_id,
      message: message,
      },
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function successCallback(data){
      $scope.thisMessage = null;
      $scope.getMessages();
      $rootScope.webSocket.send($stateParams.chatId + "|" + $rootScope.unique_id  + "|" + 'newMessage');
      $scope.markAsRead();
    })
  }
  }
```

And this is my connection with database :

```
<?php
$hostname='myhost';
$username='myuser';
$password='mypassword';

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES utf8'); 

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mydbname;charset=utf8mb4",$username,$password, $options);
    $dbh->query ('SET NAMES utf8');
    $dbh->query ('SET CHARACTER_SET utf8_unicode_ci');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Any tips or idea what I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so I have fixed my issue. The way I did it is not maybe the best one but it works. So basicaly the storing unicodes in the Database was as simple as that :

1. I changed the `header` in the file where I am inserting the data to :

   `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`
2. I again encode the message to json while inserting it like this :

   `$stmt->bindValue(':message', json_encode($data['message']));`
3. Before giving response to my app again setting the header to :

   `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

My code looks now like this :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
include_once 'config.php';

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `messages` (`message_id`, `from_account_id`, `for_account_id`, `date_read`, `message`)
      VALUES (NULL, :from_account_id, :for_account_id, NULL, :message)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':from_account_id', $data['from_account_id']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':for_account_id', $data['for_account_id']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':message', json_encode($data['message']));
    $stmt->execute();
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
          throw $e;
  }
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  echo 'Success';

?>
```

So this problem was fixed and the unicodes were stored in my DB.

Then I bacame in an awkward situation again as while getting the data from `mysql` and encoding it to `json` while sending to my app, my app couldn't return unicodes to the special characters even tho I was binding it with `ng-bind-html` and using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`. Normally I was just sending my query result as `encoded json` but it didn't work as I said. So what i did is something like that:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
include_once 'config.php';

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

try {
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from messages WHERE (from_account_id = :unique_id AND for_account_id = :user_2) OR (from_account_id = :user_2 AND for_account_id = :unique_id)");
  $stmt->bindValue(':unique_id', $data['user_1']);
  $stmt->bindValue(':user_2', $data['user_2']);
  $stmt->execute();
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
          throw $e;
      }

  $rows = $stmt->rowCount();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($rows > 0){
    $i = 0;
    echo "[";
    foreach ($result as $key => $value){
      $i++;
      echo "{";
      echo '"message_id"' . ":" . '"' .$value['message_id']. '"' .", ";
      echo '"from_account_id"' . ":" . '"' .$value['from_account_id']. '"' .", ";
      echo '"for_account_id"' . ":". '"' .$value['for_account_id']. '"' .", ";
      echo '"date_sent"' . ":" . '"' .$value['date_sent']. '"' .", ";
      echo '"date_read"' . ":" . '"' .$value['date_read']. '"' .", ";
      echo '"message"' . ":" . '"' .str_replace("\n", "</br>", json_decode($value['message'])). '"' ;
      echo "}";
      if($i != $rows){
        echo ",";
      }
      if($i == $rows){
        echo "]";
      }
      echo "\n";
    }
    exit;
  }
  else {
    echo 'Something went wrong';
    exit;
  }

?>
```

Sending decoded `json` in an string that my angularjs gets as real json made by my self was the solution.

I have added the anwser to this question as maybe someone will become in same trouble and this will be helpful.